# how to correct the indent for this line?

Tags: python, discord, bots

i followed a tutorial online : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-discord-bot-with-python/
i cant make the bot online. can someone help?

it will run an error about the secret( the secret is the token, i did this on replit)
i know that the error is about the indentation at the secret but where to place it?

error:

```
File "main.py", line 8
    client.run(my_secret)
    ^
```

below is the code. pls help thks

```
import os
import discord
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']


client = discord.Client()
  client.run(my_secret)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
  .format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
      
  if message.content.startswith('$start'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Comment: You're writing in python. Surely you should know that your indentation is very important. Remove the spacing behind the `client.run(my_secret)`.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the space before `client.run(my_secret)`